# Tool to easily create a wxPython preference dialog from a template?

Tags: python, templates, wxpython, preferences

I need a wxPython preference dialog box from a Python application. I could hand-code it (and use wxGlade to do part of the job), but I was wondering if there is no tool that makes creation of simple preference dialog boxes easier.

The 'easier' part would be in that you can specify that you need e.g. a text box, and both the GUI elements as well as the config file handling code (read/write) would be created.

I found something that is pretty close [here](http://iainmclaren.com/preferencesdialog/), but it seems a bit limited (I need some more controls, and tab pages).

Before I try to extend it, anybody knows about any other such tools?

(Ideally, the perfect tool would just take the XML file I am currently using, and would generate the Python code for the preference dialog box and writing/saving of the preferences)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article on something similar, but I used a Configuration file generated with the ConfigObj module. Here's the link:

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/01/20/generating-a-dialog-from-a-file/

You can probably take the concepts there and use them for this project.